# Loop through an array to find the index of a user input, then replace the value at the same index of another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am creating a Hangman game (with a twist) in JS/jQuery. I have figured out how to identify the index of the array of the word being guessed based on the user input (when they guess a letter). However, I cannot figure out how to take that index and replace the blank (underscoreArray) with the value of the user input at the same index.

I have tried to do this with a a conditional (at the end of the JS code), but I'm not sure how to make this work.

Upon a correct guess, this conditional should change the html from (for example, if the word is "drag" and the user guesses "d") " _ _ _ _ " to "d _ _ _".

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/minditorrey/b6ny75jm/) and here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var words = ["shade", "she mail", "queen"];
  var usedLetters = [];
  var wrongLetters = [];

  $('.play').click(function() {
    var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    var wordLength = word.length;
    var underscores = "";
    for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
      underscores = underscores + "_ ";
    }

    $('.btn-default').on('click', function() {
      var guess = $(this).text();
      if (jQuery.inArray(guess, usedLetters) === -1) {
        usedLetters.push(guess);
        $('.used').html('<p class="used">Letters used:</p><span>' + usedLetters + '</span>');
      } else {
        alert("You already guessed \"" + guess + "\"!");
      }
      /*Find out if guess = an index of word, and if it does replce the underscore index with the guess*/
      var find = word.indexOf(guess);
      var wordArray = [word];

      //loop through wordArray and where wordArray === find replace same index of underscores with guess.
      for (i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
        var underscoresArray = [underscores];
        var index = wordArray.indexOf(guess);
        if (index !== -1) {
          underscoresArray[index] = guess;
          $('#words').after(underscoresArray).toString();
        };
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please scale this down to a minimal representation of the problem and remove irrelevant code. really not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: The problem is that you seem to think that the `[]` syntax converts a string into a list of characters. When you're doing `[word]` you're creating a list of 1 element, namely 'word'. What you need to do is create a list of characters of your word, which you can do by using the `split()` method: `var characters = word.split('');`

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted that code, part of your problem lies within the part you deleted (@charlietfl just went tl;dr on you). Just remove comments, console.logs, script that renders html on the screen (i.e. "gentlemen start your engine"), or put the old code back up there and I'll edit the irrelevant part out for you.

Comment: That's what I thought! I'll put it back up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- As [@Glubus pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581860/loop-through-an-array-to-find-the-index-of-a-user-input-then-replace-the-value/35582593#comment58851131_35581860), `[word]` doesn't make a character array. Use `word.split('')`.
- You set up your `underscores` string to have spaces in it, making it twice as long as `word`, so the `index` needs to be multiplied by two to compensate
- You aren't catching every instance of a guessed letter, because `indexOf` only returns the first one

This should be closer:

```
var wordArray = word.split('');
var underscoresArray = underscores.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
  // Catch every letter, eg. the "p"s in "popcorn"
  if (wordArray[i] == guess) {
    // Underscored indices are twice the word indices
    // "popcorn" -> "p _ p _ _ _ _"
    underscoresArray[i * 2] = guess;
  };    
}
// Only need to do this once after all changes are made
underscores = underscoresArray.join(''); // Collapse back to string
$('#words').after(underscores);
console.log(underscores);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kristján. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with [@Glubus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581860/loop-through-an-array-to-find-the-index-of-a-user-input-then-replace-the-value#comment58851131_35581860) and [@Kristjan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35582593/4194343),

His solution is good, except you should also use join to bring the array back into a string before adding it into the #words element.

Edit: Kristjan updated his solution with join.

For reference, see:

- [Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)